# Fetch Data According 'pointStart' to 'pointEnd' using 'Highchart' in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, highcharts, syntax-error

I am having data in model which contain column name date which is datetime type. I am able to show my whole graph but not able to specify by date (start to End).

here is my code which  is not working.

```html
series: 
      [{
        pointInterval: <%= 1.day * 1000 %>,
        pointStart: <%= Total.reorder(:date).first.date.to_i * 1000 %>,
        pointEnd: <%= (Time.now-27.day).to_i * 1000 %>,
        name: "total-user",
        data:<%= Total.all.collect(&:total_user)%>
      }]
```

Comment: In the Highcharts is not pointEnd parameter, only pointStart. Then points are printed according to the pointInterval range.

Comment: then how to display result according to user input

Comment: You can extract two first points, calculate range, then push that value in pointInterval. In the pointStart, set value of first point. As a result all your points will be printed according to defined ranges.